# How to avoid a new request when changing an image in a hover event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I'm trying to create an event with jQuery that changes an image when the user hovers over it.
The problem I have is that even though I have preloaded the image using jQuery, when the user hovers over the image, it makes a new request and loads the image again (it is already showed in the developers console as a preloaded image since the page was first loaded). I guess there is something wrong with the way I'm changing the CSS property with jQuery, but I can't find the right way to do it anywhere.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="box" class="box">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box
{
height: 100px; 
width:  500px; 
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #003366;
background-image: url('images/blue-box.jpg');
border:1px #003366;
box-shadow: 4px 5px 2px #888888;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


var preload = [
    'css/images/blue-box.jpg',
    'css/images/gray-box.jpg'
];

preloadImages(preload);

   function preloadImages(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
    (new Image()).src = this;
    });
   }

$box = "#box";
$($box).mouseover(function()
{
    $($box).css("background-image", "url(' " + preload[1] + " ')");
});
```

});

Thanks in advance,

Diego.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the preload array to global.

```
var preload = [
    'css/images/blue-box.jpg',
    'css/images/gray-box.jpg'
];
```

and call like this

```
$(function(){
preloadImages(preload);//call the preload functions 

})
```

And I suggest you to `cache the static content resources.` such as images, css.  so that browser will read the cached images.

1. By using cache, whenever you request new image, based on your cache setting, Image will get appended a Expire headers for the response.
2. When the user request for the same image again, browser will load it from the cached images. (browser will issse `HTTP 304 Not Modifi`ed status).  until unless user wants to clear the cache.